# Sri Vaishnava English commentary to Upanishads other than Dr N.S. Anantha Rangacharya

Tags: sri-vaishnava, upanishads, book-recommendation

Is anyone aware of alternative English translations to the principal Upanishads other than the one by Dr. N.S. Anantha Rangacharya for the bhashya by Ranga Ramanuja Muni? I know there is one for Isavasya, I am looking for the translations for the remaining ones.